# pytesserect error: file not found, TesseractNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting strange errors while using pytesseract, could someone please help. I'm using python 3.5 in jupyter notebook and here is what I tried:

```
pip install pillow
pip install pytesseract
```

I can see relevant folder in v3.5 environment, then in notebook I tried:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("sample01.png")))
```

I have saved sample01.png in the same folder as my notebook. But the above line throws:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TesseractNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b37d854f093a> in <module>()
----> 1 print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("sample01.png")))
```

Appreciate any help!

PS: the solution was to first install tesseract from their github account and then follow the accepted answer on the linked question.